# View windows environment variables in Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, environment-variables

Is there a way to sync windows environment variables with Cygwin?

For example, in CMD `echo %inetroot%` gives the path to a project build. Is it possible to transfer this env variable to Cygwin such that `echo $inetroot` provides the same path?

Thanks!

Comment: When I use the `env` command in Cygwin's shell I see all of my usual Windows environment variables. Don't you?

Comment: My bad, I'm still fairly new. The `env` command did it for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `env` program to so that ... or `echo "$inetroot"`. I think the variable names are **case-sensitive**, though (in Bash and thus MinGW).

Those variables are all available in MinGW from Windows (user profile and global). Again, use `env` to list them or for example `env|grep -i inetroot` to find the properly capitalized version of the variable name.

Comment: `echo ${PATH}` seems to me like a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @CoDEmanX: cleaner solution for what? Currently I fail to see any connection to the question or my answer.

Comment: Nvm, this post came up on Google when I tried to retrieve Windows env var PATH in cygwin.